# Choosing a question from iOS Spotlight search does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, ios-app, search-indexing

If I search from Spotlight (to the left of the first home screen), Stack Exchange results may appear:

[image: results]

I tap on a question…

[image: tap]

And it opens the app, just like it was when I last closed it:

[image: meta SE]

<sup>**Note**:  [here’s a link](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc15/709) to the appropriate WWDC talk (for Apple devs)</sup>

- App Version: 1.5.1.2
- Device: iPhone 5c (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.1 (Build 13E238)

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.

The code assumed that `window.rootViewController` would be the activity restoring view controller, which it was before the post drafting enhancements, so it was calling `-[SEDraftIndicatingViewController restoreUserActivityState:]` which was a noop.

Comment: Got an ETA for the update?

Comment: @JF It's in beta testing right now.  Should be out by the end of the month.